# Loop to unfilter multiple excel workbooks VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do a loop to unfilter the column A for all the workbooks (as they are the same, alwyas column A).
I want to show all the cells as the filter romve the empty cells.
I have many of folders ( more than 50) so the loop is very useful and important for the next step of my code.

I have a code that works for one folder:

```
`Sub unfilterr()
Dim y As Workbook, myfile, FolderPath, path
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set y = Workbooks.Open("Z:\VBA\Copie de Devis_65 Version 
avec G35.xlsx")
With y.Worksheets("Para RF")
    If Not y.Worksheets("Para RF").AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
            y.Sheets("Para RF").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1
    End If
End With
End Sub`
```

and now trying to do the loop:

```
`Sub unfilter1()
Dim y As Workbook, myfile, FolderPath, path
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

'## Open workbooks first:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual



FolderPath = "Z:\VBA\Test\"
path = FolderPath & "*.xls*"
myfile = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")

Do While myfile <> ""

Set y = Workbooks.Open(path) 'I put path instead of myfile because I have error if I put myfile

Set ws = y.Worksheets("Para RF")
'With ws
    If Not ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
            y.Sheets("Para RF").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1
    End If
'End With

myfile = Dir()
y.Close saveChanges:=True
Loop


MsgBox ("Task Complete")
End Sub
```

can you please tell what is the problem with this loop!?
I am trying it on 4 workbooks in the test folder! only the first one is unfiltered while the others are not. It seems like the loop is repeting on only the first workbook in the folder.

So with this loop no error message but the result is unsatisfing.

Thank you a lot for your help.

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The Workbook.Open() method needs a full path and the filename.

Replace

```
 Set y = Workbooks.Open(path)
```

With

```
Set y = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & myfile)
```

and you should be good to go.
You don't need the path variable.

Edit: I minimized your whole script to the bare minimum to loop through all "*.xls*" files and open all off them within a folder:

```
Sub OpenWorkbooks()
Dim y As Workbook
Dim myfile As String
Dim FolderPath As String

FolderPath = "C:\TestDirectory\"
myfile = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")

Do While myfile <> ""
    Set y = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & myfile) 
    myfile = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

The above opens each Excel file in `C:\TestDirectory\` on my machine.
N.b. make sure you have the "\" at the end of the `FolderPath` variable, otherwise it'll look for `C:\TestDirectorySomeFileName.xlsx` which is not going to work.

Comment: I tried it! It didn't work! same as the beggining, no error message and no changes :(

Comment: Hm that's strange. This runs perfectly here. You're not on a mac, are you?

Comment: It was my mistake :) I have wrote `saveChanges:= False` so the changes haven't been saved lol

Comment: Hahaha yeah happens. Glad you found it.